# Does a DSLR lens have a shutter speed?

Tags: dslr, shutter-speed

I was analysing the combination of a Nikon D5600 and AF-P DX NIKKOR 10-20MM F/4.5-5.6G VR, mainly for Northern lights photo purpose.

The Nikkor lens which I am analysing is not a fast lens so I will need use slow shutter. I noticed that D5600 has a 30 second slowest shutter speed, but [according to Amazon.in](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B072639587/?coliid=I2AIP9BD79O5N0&colid=1XP33IM5PNIC6&psc=1&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it), the lens has 20 second shutter speed.

Does a lens have a "shutter speed"? And if so, in this scenario what will be the shutter speed used while using them in combination, will it be 20 second or 30 second?

Comment: @Lokesh Neither the [Nikon](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/camera-lenses/af-p-dx-nikkor-10-20mm-f%252f4.5-5.6g-vr.html#tab-ProductDetail-ProductTabs-TechSpecs) site or [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Nikon-AF-P-NIKKOR-10-20mm-4-5-5-6G/dp/B072639587/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=AF-P%2BDX%2BNIKKOR%2B10-20MM%2BF%2F4.5-5.6G%2BVR&qid=1603642965&sr=8-1&th=1) in the US mention anything about a minimum shutter speed.  Unless proven otherwise, I'd be thinking that this is a description error on Amazon in India.

Comment: @PeterM : Thanks for info.

Comment: @MikeSowsun - perhaps so, but sometimes i feel an answer correcting a false assumption will aid others later. It's unlikely that only one person in the world has ever had that thought, especially as misinformation on a sales site reinforces the misconception. [I also just found the same information on Amazon UK, so wherever it's sourced, it appears widespread] [link](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Nikon-NIKKOR-10-20mm-4-5-5-6G-Black/dp/B072639587)

Comment: The shutter speed associated with the lens is certainly an error.  That said... there is such a thing as lenses that do have built-in shutters (leaf shutters).  But these are not very common anymore.  

Also, the Nikon D5600 does support "Bulb" mode which gives you exposure times as long as you want.  In that mode (it's my understanding the camera must be in Manual exposure mode to access Bulb shutter mode) the shutter remains open as long as you hold the shutter button down.  To avoid camera shake, the shutter is normally controlled via a remote shutter release.

Comment: Even on amazon.fr, plenty of bizarre things in the specs, besides the 20s shutter speed. The aperture is 4.5 millimeters, and technically it's a DSLR.  Also, its cousin the 10-24mm is credited with a 20x zoom range.

Comment: @TimCampbell, I'm not sure that it's right to say that old lenses _have_ shutters. Am I mis-remembering? or was it typical back in the days of press cameras and view cameras to say that one was using such-and-such lens, mounted _in_ such-and-such shutter? (i.e., as if the lens and the shutter were purchased separately, and assembled into a unit by the photographer?)

Comment: @SolomonSlow It's fairly common for large and medium format cameras to use leaf-shutters in the lens.  It was common on older SLRs (e.g. Zeiss Contaflex, Kodak Retina Reflex, etc.)  I've never heard of a modern DSLR having any lens offered with an in-lens shutter.

Comment: @TimCampbell, I was thinking specifically of view cameras and press cameras, where each lens/shutter assembly is semi-permanently mounted to an interchangeable [_lens board_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_board). I thought I remembered literature about such cameras saying that the lens was "mounted _in_ the shutter," (front and back parts of the lens separately attached to the front and back of the shutter body.) It might be a moot point when talking about rangefinder cameras (e.g., Kodak Retina) in which the lens/shutter assembly is integral with the whole of the camera.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, lenses don't have a maximum shutter time. They just let light through continuously, blocked by the camera's shutter from hitting the sensor.

You are also not limited by the camera's internal shutter speeds [at the long end]. Even though the camera's maximum internally-timed shutter is 30 seconds, it also has two 'long' modes, Bulb & Time. These are available in manual mode only.
They are essentially the same thing, but triggered slightly differently.
Bulb will keep the shutter open so long as the release button is held, Time will open on the first press, close on the second.

This would all be made considerably less shaky by using a cheap wired remote* from eBay [$£€ 10 or so]. Also using either live view, mirror up or a shutter release delay.

*These things are very basic, and tend to have a user interface that makes a 1980s digital watch look the height of GUI design, but at most simple you don't even need to put batteries in them. They will work in normal, bulb or time mode simply by pressing/holding the release button. They even have a half squeeze focussing, exactly like the on-camera release.

Comment: Just for completeness, you might note that some medium format lenses do indeed include a shutter in the lens. Not relevant for 35mm SLRs.

Comment: @EricS Even less relevant for DSLRs.

Comment: @ZeissIkon There are digital backs for some Hasselblads which classify as a DSLR with a shutter in the lens so not completely irrelevant.

Comment: @EricS I thought I recently saw a description of a DSLR or MILC that had leaf shutter lenses.  Don't remember any details unfortunately.

Comment: There could be a limitation on maximum automatic shutter speed obtainable with metering, due to limitations on lens speed vs meter sensitivity.

Answer (score -1):

The that 20 is the maximum focal length of the lens, not shutter speed. The shutter speed is only for the camera body, since the shutter is located in the camera body, not in the lens.

Comment: The lens is from a 3rd-party seller on Amazon India. Likely, the details are a poor translation or misunderstanding of specs that were copied from another site.